# Validation in React To-do app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple to-do app and trying to do validation for adding new task mainly I want to prevent user to add a blank task to the list - my React skills are very poor so please forgive this silly question.
if you have any idea how to solve my problem please let me know thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import List from './List';
import '../App.css';


class App extends Component {

    state = {
        query: '',
        inputValue: '',
        todos: [
            { value: 'Naumiej  się Reacta', done: false },
            { value: 'Pucuj trzewiki ', done: true },
        ],
        direction: 'row',
        justify: 'left',
        alignItems: 'left',
    }

    handleChange = (evt) => {
        this.setState({ inputValue: evt.target.value });
    }

    removeMe = (index) => {
        this.setState({
            todos: this.state.todos.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
        })
    }

    searchChanged = (evt) => {
        this.setState({ query: evt.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit = (evt) => {

        if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
            const newTodo = {
                value: this.state.inputValue,
                done: false
            };
            const todos = this.state.todos.concat(newTodo);
            this.setState({ todos: todos, inputValue: '' })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Grid item xs={12} style={{ padding: 30, display: 'flex' }}>
                <div className="App">
                    <Typography type="body1'" color="inherit" text-align='left'>
                        <AppBar position="static" color="default" style={{ flexDirection: 'center' }}>
                            <Toolbar>
                                <TextField
                                    style={{ float: 'left', paddingRight: 40, }}
                                    placeholder="Add Task ..."
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
                                    onKeyDown={this.handleSubmit}
                                >
                                </TextField>
                                <TextField ype="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={this.searchChanged} />

                            </Toolbar>
                        </AppBar>
                    </Typography>
                    <Paper>
                        <List style={{ marginTop: 90 }}
                            removeMe={this.removeMe}
                            todos={this.state.todos}
                            query={this.state.query}
                        />
                    </Paper>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did correctly. Just return before submit or check for value with enter key.

```
handleSubmit = (evt) => {

    if (evt.keyCode === 13 && this.state.inputValue) {
        const newTodo = {
            value: this.state.inputValue,
            done: false
        };
        const todos = this.state.todos.concat(newTodo);
        this.setState({todos: todos, inputValue: ''})
    }
}
```